# Replicating Non-Existing Nodes From Example XML to Identity Transform Using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to add new nodes into my identity transform so the output will also include the new nodes.

Here is my identity transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="FIELD1"></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ROWSET">
    <listing>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </listing>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ROW">
    <listing>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </listing>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="FIELD2">
    <title lang="en_US">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </title>"
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="FIELD5">
    <content lang="en_US">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </content>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="FIELD6">
    <price>
        <!-- output Salary as custom text -->
        <xsl:text>Salary is </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </price>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="FIELD4">
    <region>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"></xsl:apply-templates> 
    </region>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="FIELD3">
    <custom name="client">
        <xsl:text>Company name is </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </custom>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="FIELD7">
    <custom name="link">            
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"></xsl:apply-templates>            
    </custom>
</xsl:template>
<!-- output result -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>                      
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The example XML that I want my identity transform to replicate is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<listings>
<listing>
    <title lang="en_US"><![CDATA[Title in USmana1]]></title>
    <content lang="en_US"><![CDATA[Lor4em ipsum dolor sit amet,     consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id nulla dolor. Ut aliquet, mauris id molestie porttitor, dui lorem pretium sem, quis vestibulum orci purus ultrices lacus. Nulla accumsan tortor porta nibh consequat rhoncus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi elementum venenatis ante eu porta. Curabitur ultricies nunc vel elit rutrum scelerisque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse rutrum lectus quis sem malesuada nec placerat sapien malesuada.]]></content>
    <category lang="en_US">Auto</category>
    <contactemail>email@yahoo.com</contactemail>
    <contactname>Mr. False Name1</contactname>
    <price>123.45</price>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <city_area>07841454774</city_area>
    <city>Arizona</city>
    <region>Arizona</region>
    <countryId>US</countryId>
    <country>United States</country>
    <custom name="client">Companie</custom>
    <custom name="tip">Vanzare</custom>
    <image>http://conejo.me/cats/153.jpg</image>
    <image>http://conejo.me/cats/598.jpg</image>
    <image>http://conejo.me/cats/1908.jpg</image>
    <datetime>2013-03-08 12:34:56</datetime>
</listing>
<listing>
    <title lang="en_US"><![CDATA[Title in English 2]]></title>
    <content lang="en_US"><![CDATA[Lor3em ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id nulla dolor. Ut aliquet, mauris id molestie porttitor, dui lorem pretium sem, quis vestibulum orci purus ultrices lacus. Nulla accumsan tortor porta nibh consequat rhoncus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi elementum venenatis ante eu porta. Curabitur ultricies nunc vel elit rutrum scelerisque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse rutrum lectus quis sem malesuada nec placerat sapien malesuada.]]></content>
    <category lang="en_US">Real-Estate</category>
    <contactemail>your.false123@email.com</contactemail>
    <contactname>Mrs. True Name 123 1</contactname>
    <price>98.76</price>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <city_area>0845744774</city_area>
    <city>Bucks</city>
    <region>Arizona</region>
    <countryId>US</countryId>
    <country>United States</country>
    <custom name="client">Companie</custom>
    <custom name="tip">Inchiriere</custom>
    <image>http://conejo.me/cats/13.jpg</image>
    <image>http://conejo.me/cats/598.jpg</image>
    <image>http://conejo.me/cats/1908.jpg</image>
    <datetime>2012-08-03 12:34:56</datetime>
</listing>
```

As you can see, my transform isn't included the nodes such as category.  How can I add non existing node (i.e., not match in the XML which needs to be transformed) into my identity transform so I can replicate the structure of the example XML which I had pasted above?

--- additional info ---

Snippet of my original XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
   <ROW>
      <FIELD1></FIELD1> 
      <FIELD2>job_title</FIELD2>
      <FIELD3>company</FIELD3>
      <FIELD4>location</FIELD4>
      <FIELD5>description</FIELD5>
      <FIELD6>salary</FIELD6>
      <FIELD7>link</FIELD7>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <FIELD1>1</FIELD1>
      <FIELD2>ADMINSTRATIVE ASSISTANT</FIELD2>
      <FIELD3>            Company name [here]</FIELD3>
      <FIELD4>Georgia</FIELD4>
      <FIELD5>A great place to work for…</FIELD5>
      <FIELD6>$53,000 </FIELD6>
      <FIELD7>[Link](blah.com)</FIELD7>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <FIELD1>2</FIELD1>
      <FIELD2>OFFICE SPECIALIST</FIELD2>
      <FIELD3>        Company name [here]</FIELD3>
      <FIELD4>Georgia</FIELD4>
      <FIELD5>Provide customer service to patient…</FIELD5>
      <FIELD6>$43,000 </FIELD6>
      <FIELD7>[Link](blah.com)</FIELD7>
   </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

---- More detail: ----

What I'm trying to do is to transform the original XML to look like the example XML I had posted earlier.  Nonetheless, the original XML does not have nodes such as category, email, and so forth.  I want to add similar nodes from example XML so I can have an XML page that I could feed to a plugin which will insert the data into my database.  The plugin that I'm using for a piece of software is so specific that if an XML structure isn't similar to the example XML's structure, the plugin would fail to insert the data into the database.

Comment: Identity transforms essentially copies source document. You can always add new nodes after in a different template. Please post original xml snippet so we can see what you are attempting to do.

Comment: I just update my question with more details.

Comment: Would you want the new nodes to be output as empty elements, or did you want some default value in then?

Comment: New nodes should have default value that I set.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order of the elements in the output is not important, you can just output the extra nodes in the template that matches the `ROW` element

```
<xsl:template match="ROW">
    <listing>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        <category>Default Category</category>
        <contactemail>Default Email</contactemail>
        <contactname>Default Contact</contactname>
    </listing>
</xsl:template>
```

However, if the order was important, and you did want the extra nodes output in a specific position, you could do this by explicitly selecting the existing nodes, and outputing the extra nodes in-between, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="ROW">
    <listing>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="FIELD1|FIELD2" />
        <category>Default Category</category>
        <contactemail>Default Email</contactemail>
        <contactname>Default Contact</contactname>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="FIELD3|FIELD4|FIELD5|FIELD6|FIELD7" />
    </listing>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tim C.  I just wonder, in XML, is the new line important?  As I'm trying out the solution of yours, it seems that the new nodes are stringing on the same line.

Comment: Try adding an `indent` to the `xsl:output` command. `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />`